# Do complex data-type parameters for @AuraEnable methods now all need to be global in Winter'23?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

We're doing some testing of our managed packaged in a Winter '23 org and noticed that some of the existing functionality is now broken.

Looking at the debug logs I can see this type of error appearing which is referencing a public class with a public constructor that is used as a parameter for a @AuraEnabled method

```
public class MyController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static void myMethod(myNs.myClassName myParameter) {
        System.debug(myParameter);
    }
}
```

> System.TypeException: myNs.myClassName does not have a no-arg
> constructor

The release notes mention something that suggests we now need to switch all our complex data-type parameter classes to be global instead of public. If this is the case it seems a bit strange how the @AuraEnabled class & method can still be public but the parameter classes need to be global. Is there another way of resolving this issue without converting our parameter classes to global?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_block_public_constructor_package.htm&type=5&release=240